# Where do you store "generic" class methods?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, design-patterns

So let's say I have an Person entity:

```
PERSON  
ID  
FirstName  
LastName  
SSN   
LastModifiedDate
```

After this table exists in the database, and is part of my .edmx file, I usually create a partial class for the entity to use to perform some object-specific work.  For example, with the Person entity I might have an UpdateLastModifiedDate() method which would simply set the value for the LastModifiedDate field to the present date and time for the selected object.

My question, however has to do with more "generic" methods, that don't relate to any specific object.  For example, let's say I wanted to create a GetPersonBySSN() method which would accept a SSN and return the Person object with that SSN (if it exists).  Where would I store this method?

I couldn't store it in the partial class (could I?) because I would have to do something odd like this:

```
Person myPerson = db.Person.where(u => u.ID = 12345);
Person myPerson2 = myPerson.GetPersonBySSN(123456789);
```

It just doens't make sense to do it this way.

Also, I am reluctant to create a second static class to store these "generic" methods (like maybe a PersonGenericMethods class) because it feels like I should be able to do this with only the main class, Person.

Where would you store these "generic" methods?

---

Edit: I am using ASP.NET MVC and would like recommendations on how to best build using this.

Comment: When you say, *"I couldn't store it in the partial class; It just doens't make sense to do it this way"* and *"I am reluctant to create a second static class to store these "generic" methods"*, that leaves you with zero options, doesn't it?

Comment: Rufus- you're correct.  I was hoping there was another way, but it sounds like there is not.  So I would just create a [ClassName]Repository class for EVERY entity in the database that I want to interact with?  If so, would these repository classes also contain the business logic?

Comment: @RufusL An option to create a second non-static class remains - that's what Stanley suggests in his answer.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Ah, right. Missed the 'static' part of that quote! I read it as, "I don't want to add it to the Person class and I don't want to create a new class".

Comment: You *could* put it in the partial class as a static method.  That way you could call `Person.GetPersonBySSN()` - but you would typically need to pass in the database context as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

> Also, I am reluctant to create a second class to store these "generic" methods (like maybe a PersonGenericMethods class) because it feels like I should be able to do this with only the main class, Person.

How a bout a `PersonRepository` class?  That class would be responsible for interacting with the underlying `Person` data store - getting, updating, deleting, etc.

What you seem to want is called the [Active Record Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern)
 where entity classes are responsible for creating, updating, and deleting themselves.  While that's more common in other platforms like Ruby, in most .NET architectures the separation of the entity from the repository is more common.

The more separation you have (entities, repositories, business logic, UI logic, etc.) the more flexibility and re-usability you have.  That comes, however, at the price of additional complexity.

Comment: Would these repository classes also contain business logic?  If not, where would that go? Would it require a third set of classes, like this: 1) the original entity class 2) the repository class for interacting with the data 3) a business logic class for this type of entity.

Comment: @user7560542 As little as possible - typically yes, business logic would be done in a separate layer.  See my edit.

Comment: Thanks Stanley. Is there a specific name to your pattern (repository)?  Also, I am using ASP.NET MVC.  Is this pattern relevant for MVC?

Comment: Yes repository is the pattern name And it is absolutely relevant for MVC - in fact many of the templates that were available for early versions of MVC used this pattern by default.

Answer (score 1):

The repository-pattern is perfect for this.
Do keep in mind that you are programming OO. It is strange to get the person from 'itself'.

A repository will get your data and return your desired result.

on a side-note:

```
Person myPerson = db.Person.where(u => u.ID = 12345);
Person myPerson2 = myPerson.GetPersonBySSN(123456789);
```

Is strange, first, you get the person where ID = ... and then as function on the person you want to make sure that ssn is the same number?

your repo would look like this:

```
public class PersonRepository
{

 private readonly DBContext _myContext'
 public PersonRepository(DBContext myContext)
 { 
   _myContext = myContext; //<== Dependency INjection 
  }

  public function Person GetBySSN(int ssn)
  {
    return _myContext.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ssn = ssn);
   }
 }
```

take a look at: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

just gives a good basis.

and then for later improvements: can you look into `Maybe` and `Results` types, but if your new to this, forget it :)

enjoy!